# Import secondary audio track along with video mpg into Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, audio

I've been trying for hours to import an mpg along with its secondary audio track into Adobe Premiere Pro.  Only the primary track is imported.

I know this mpg has two tracks because I can play the file in the VLC player with the setting Audio > Audio Track > Track 2 [Spanish] and the secondary audio track plays.

- I have tried setting audio preferences insuring all default audio
  tracks are using "Use File".
- I have tried setting the track tab in a new sequence to
  "multichannel" with "number of channels" = 2.
- I have also tried modifying the imported mp3's audio channels.

I have also searched online and in YouTube but still no answers.

Please advise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7470396#7470396), it should work with Adobe Premiere CC.
And after importing it should look like this:
[image]

If you are using a really old version of Adobe Premiere, you could download the latest trial version to check it.